# Merging with background while thresholding

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am doing a project on License plate recognition system.
But I am facing problem in segmenting license plate characters.
I have tried cvAdaptiveThreshold() with different window sizes,
otsu and niblacks algorithm.

But in most of the cases license plate characters merge with the
background.
Sample images and outputs given below,

[image]

[image]

1. In the first image all the license plate characters are connected by a white line in the bottom hence using thresholding algorithm i couldn't extract characters, how can I extract characters from those  images... ??
2. In the second image noise  in the background merges with foreground, which connects all the characters together.. How can I segment characters in these  types of images..??
3. Is there any segmentation algorithms which can segment characters in the second image.. ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Merge with the background"? That you are unable to segment them?

Comment: Yes, unable to segment.

Comment: When you say "unable to segment", what is wrong with the Otsu segmentation result (top image, right column, blue title background)? Looks pretty segmented to me...

Comment: In that all the characters are combined by a white line in the bottom, so those characters are segmented as a one contour.

Comment: You might want to try to blur the image before you try to segment them. This removes the result of noise somewhat.

Comment: I think blurring will combine adjacent characters if they are close... –

Comment: @user61455 how did it work out?

Answer (score 0):

1. Preprocessing: find big black areas on your image and mark it as background. 
   Do this for example with treshold. Another way might be to use [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) (contourArea to get the size on the result).
   This way you know what areas you can colour black after step 1.
2. Use OTSU (top image, right column, blue title background).
3. Colour everything you know to be background black.
4. Use Opening/Closing or Erode/Dilate (not sure which will work better) to get rid of small lines and to refine your results
   Alternatively you could make an edge detection and merge all areas that are "close together", like the second 3 in your example. You could check if areas are close together with a distance between the bounding box of your contours.

ps: I don't think you should blur your image, since it seems to be pretty small already.

Comment: Opening/Closing, Erode/Dilate operations sometimes merge adjacent characters or breaks single character in to two different parts..